# Turn Layer off by default in Leaflet LayerControl

Tags: python, leaflet, folium, layer-control

In the following python code I have three data layers while I need to show only two of them by default as the program executes. So the **Places** and **District** layer should be checked as the map is opened and the **Country** layer should be unchecked/turned off. What should I write in *LayerControl* for this?

```
import folium
import pandas

data=pandas.read_csv("Previous.csv")
data = data[data['Death'] > 0]
lat = list(data["Latitude"])
lon = list(data["Longitude"])
dat = list(data["Date"])
are = list(data["Area"])
sym = list(data["Symptoms"])
tra = list(data["Area_traveled"])
sou = list(data["Source"])
dea = list(data["Death"])

def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation <= 1:
        return 'orange'
    elif 1 < elevation <= 3:
        return 'red'
    elif 3 < elevation :
        return 'darkred'


fga = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Places")
map = folium.Map(location=[23.789412, 90.351756], zoom_start=7, tiles="Mapbox Bright")
for lt, ln, co, mo, vi, up, na, de  in zip(lat, lon, dat, are, sym, tra, sou, dea):
    fga.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius = str(de), popup= "<br><a href="+na+">Link </a></b>" + na + "<br><b>Area: </b>" + co + "<br><b>Symptoms : </b>" + vi + "<br><b>Area traveled : </b>" + mo+ "<br><b>Source : </b>" + up,
    fill = 'true', fill_color = color_producer(de), color = 'grey', fill_opacity=0.7))

fgp = folium.FeatureGroup(name="District")
fgp.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open("dist.geojson",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read(), style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'grey' if x['properties']['Death'] == 0
else 'darkred'}))

fgq = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Country")

fgq.add_child(folium.GeoJson(open("world.json",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read(), style_function=lambda x: {
'fillColor': 'none'}))

map.add_child(fga)
map.add_child(fgp)
map.add_child(fgq)
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
map.save("Corona.html")
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used Python, but if you look at the Folium docs at https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html?highlight=featuregroup#folium.map.FeatureGroup, you'll se that `folium.map.FeatureGroup` class has `show` parameter.

Docs say: `show (bool, default True) – Whether the layer will be shown on opening (only for overlays).` Setting this parameter to `false` should do it.